# Can Django-cms pages incorporate the vary_on_headers decorator?

Tags: django, caching, django-cms

I'm building a site using Django-CMS and we're using [MobileESP](https://code.google.com/p/mobileesp/source/browse/#svn/Python) to detect the user-agent and serve different templates and content depending on what device is being used to the view the site.

The issue is that with django-cms's built in page caching, users are seeing the wrong content depending on which version of the page was cached.  For example, if the desktop version of the site is viewed first and then cached, then users visiting the site on a smartphone still see the desktop version instead of the mobile version.

With traditional Django views this could be resolved using the @vary_on_headers('User-Agent') to ensure different versions of the site get correctly cached.

Is it possible to apply this logic to Django-CMS views some how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure out a way to work around this issue by using the patch_vary_headers() functionality in a custom middleware class.  I already had a platform detection middleware which added the mobile/desktop setting to the request object.  So I just added a process_response function to the middleware and patched it there.  So far it appears to be working correctly.

```
class PlatformDetectionMiddleWare (object):

    def process_request(self, request):
        user_agent = request.META.get("HTTP_USER_AGENT")
        http_accept = request.META.get("HTTP_ACCEPT")

        agent = mdetect.UAgentInfo(userAgent=user_agent, httpAccept=http_accept)
        request.is_tablet = agent.detectTierTablet()
        request.is_mobile = agent.detectTierIphone()

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        patch_vary_headers(response, ['User-Agent'])
        return response
```

Answer (score 1):

http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter15.html I think you can caching like SI Eric suggest and this link talk about caching with vary_header I think it's can help to solve your problem.
I cache on view layer with

```
@vary_on_headers('User-Agent')
```

in my project and it run quite well!